# How would I use pandoc to convert this Overleaf tex project into a word document?

Tags: xetex, overleaf, pandoc, conversion

How would I use pandoc to convert [this](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/jason-richards-resume/chbxgnfyyvfc) Overleaf project to .docx?

I've tried `pandoc -o output.docx -t docx resume.tex` but all I get is a blank document. I believe the problem has something to do with the \import commands in resume.tex but I'm pretty new to Latex so would definitely appreciate some insight here.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain better, for example did you get an error message?

Comment: Hi, there were no error messages. The command executed without any issues. The problem is that it didn't do anything. The resulting docx file was simply blank.

Comment: pandoc is going to have fairly minimal support for a non-standard document class like in your link; I suspect you'd have better luck with using `make4ht` to convert to odt, then opening the odt in Word. However, for testing purposes, do you know of a way to get the full template, including the imported files, without an Overleaf account? (I don't have or want one.)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible :(